# How return count of documents that match a given criteria using the php driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

The documents in my collection look like this:

```
{
    "state": "Wyoming",
    "high": {
        "fahrenheit": 115,
        "city": "Basin"
    },
    "low": {
        "fahrenheit": -63,
        "city": "Moran"
    }
}
```

Show the total number of documents where the high fahrenheit temperature is greater than or equal to 120 and the low fahrenheit temperature is less than or equal to -60.

Comment: How is your collection model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in shell, the PHP driver provides the [`.count`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.count.php) method which is exactly what you need here, also in order to access the "fahrenheit" field in your embedded document to you need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) .

```
$collection->count(
    array(
        "high.fahrenheit" => array("$gte" => 120),
        "low.fahrenheit" => array("$lte" => -60)
    )
)
```

This is equivalent to the following query in the shell:

```
db.collection.count({ 
    "high.fahrenheit": { "$gte": 120 }, 
    "low.fahrenheit": { "$lte": -60 } 
})
```